# How can i prevent objecbox-jni linkage error?

Tags: objectbox

When start the App it always show followring errors.

BoxStore Linkage error: Beginning load of objectbox-jni...
BoxStore Linkage error: objectbox-jni (3.5.1) was loaded normally!

May I ignore errors?

gradle file add bundle > abi > enableSplit doesn't help.

```
bundle {
    abi {
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not enough information. Please give some details about your configuration and a full exception message/stack.